# checking an array of string objects for null values

Tags: c#, null-check

This is a fairly basic question I think but either my brain hasn't woken up yet or I'm just being thick!

I have a class that has a property of a collection of strings defined below (names are simplified)

```
public class IdentifierCollection : BaseSubCollection, IIdentifierCollection
{
    public string Id1{ get; set; }
    public string Id2{ get; set; }
    public string Id3{ get; set; }
    // ...      
}
```

I want to check if any of the properties actually have a value before saving so I am currently doing something like this...

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id2) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id2) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id3) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id4) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id5) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id6) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id7) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id8))
{

}
```

Just typing this feels wrong!! There must be a better way...

Comment: Why do you have numbered properties? Why not use a dictionary or list? You could use reflection to find and inspect the properties though, if you can't lose them.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm wondering if that's the effect of _"(names simplfied)"_.  If it _isn't_, then there may well be a very different answer to the Q, ie what you're suggesting...

Comment: Yeah it is, the actual names are what I'm working on which is vaguely confidentual

Comment: But using reflection would be more expensive than just ugly code... or not?

Comment: Do you actually access these properties by name somewhere, or is a dictionary still an option? And define "expensive". Yes, reflection is "relatively slow", but it is backed by the runtime caching various objects.

Comment: If `IIdentifierCollection` hints that is a collection why does it not implement IEnumerable? You could then just iterate over it with a foreach or something.

Comment: Yeah they are used and they make up the Poco and JSON objects that are then saved to DocumentDb

Comment: That might be a better solution @Neijwiert... will try it now, feel free to add it as an answer!

Comment: And if its not just pure string you could do IEnumerable<Object> and then a foreach(Object identifier in theidentifierobject) { if(identifier as String != null) { blah blah

Comment: @Neijwiert keeping in mind that the OP wants to keep the properties there: how can you iterate over a singular class with properties? You can create an enumerator that iterates over the properties and returns their values, but then you're back to square one.

Comment: How many times do you call this method (checking any of the properties being null) and how many such objects do you have? Are there different types of configurations: e.g. checking only some of the properties being null based on some criteria, etc.?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see any other 'clean' solution. If they are separate member variables. Reflection don't seem clean to me. If you force the coder to implement the iterator then it is going to work for every newly made class that implements IIdentifierCollection.

Comment: @Neijwiert "doesn't seem clean" is an opinion. Reflection is more fool-proof than a hand-coded enumerator that contains of just `yield return Id1; yield return Id2;` and so on, because it is error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with this kind of property checking. Using reflection or implementing some interface just to be able to iterate over the properties looks like overkill to me. Though I agree that such a long statement looks awkward as a conditional check. To make the code more readable I'd extract this check to a separate private method.

```
if (NoPropIsNullOrEmpty())
{
}

private bool NoPropIsNullOrEmpty()
{
    return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id2) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id2) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id3) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id4) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id5) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id6) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id7) ||
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryObj.Identifiers?.Id8));
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to agree, the BaseCollection does implement an indexer so that I can access the properties as if they were an array, so the IEnumerable made sense but it ends up being overkill to avoid a few ugly lines of code... I've taken it out to a helper method already so I guess I'm just being too picky!!!

Comment: _"I don't think there is anything wrong with this kind of property checking"_ - it's copy-paste code, so subject to all drawbacks thereof.